Shortcut for commenting out code is not working in visual studio assembly language
I'm trying to learn x86 assembly language. The commenting of code isn't working for my visual studio community 2022. When I try to press keys ctrl+k and ctrl+c it's showing 'the key section is bound to command (comment section) which is not currently available'. Comment button in taskbar is also grayed out. How can I solve this issue?

I'm guessing your copy of VS doesn't know how to comment x86 assembly. There are probably some assembly development tools you need to install.

which one specifically to install? will you please elaborate
